# add two locations to domain controller

Tags: active-directory, domain

hi guys I wanna add a domain controller that ties into our existing domain controller at a different site, two different networks, and site to site VPN is not my first choice, is there any way I can add two domain controllers over the internet to access the same records?

Comment: IMHO, connecting branch offices into a domain can only be done securely over a VPN connection. Under no circumstances should a domain controller be internet facing. Windows Server has all the built in VPN capabilities without needing additional software or hardware. *Don't* open your domain to the public internet.

Comment: @StackOverflowisdead thanks would you mind giving me some search terms? so I can figure out how to do it without bothering everyone

Comment: IsaacFinkelstein, split the problem into two parts. (1) secure connection from remote office to existing datacentre. Keywords: VPN. Optional keywords IPSec, OpenVPN, Firewall. (2) running up a second domain controller. Keywords: Second Domain Controller

Comment: Look into Microsoft DirectAccess. It's basically an implementation of VPN but built in and optimised for Windows. https://docs.microsoft.com/nl-nl/windows-server/remote/remote-access/directaccess/directaccess